# Levi subgroup of Siegel parabolic of GSpin

Tags: rt.representation-theory, algebraic-groups

I consider the group $G=\mathrm{GSpin(V)}$ as in [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/49722/a-question-about-hodge-structures-associated-to-spinor-groups) question.

We have the so called Siegel parabolic $P$ (after fixing a cocharacter) and the associated Levi $M$ (these can also be obtained using the corresponding objects in $\mathrm{GSp}$).

> Can we describe explicitly $M$?

I think it is isomorphic to some product of $\mathrm{GL}_i$, but I am not sure.

Comment: I think that if you indeed want to get an answer, you should make an effort to explain clearly what you are asking....

Answer (score 1):

The Levi part would be $GL(n)\times GL(1)$. By the way, the Siegel parabloic is not unique in the even rank case.

Comment: Could you explain why this is the Levi part?